# Installing Ubuntu, on a Windows 8 laptop, without a CD. Can it be done? And what is the normal time for download?

Tags: installation, windows, windows-8, downloads, time

I have a Aspire laptop, Windows 8 pre-installed with 8 GB of ram. I have tried to download via thumb drive but it won't download. So I wanted to know there were any other ways to download it without a CD. Is it normal for a download to be longer than 4 hours?(That's with bios)

Comment: Download Ubuntu doesn't take long, do it from Ubuntu.com or one of the torrents. installing Ubuntu is easiest to do from a live-cd, so install Ubuntu on a usb-stick and then boot from that. search on the site for it, there are a bunch of questions on this topic, this question will be most likely closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Under windows, the best tool to transfer the Ubuntu installer to a flash drive is the LinuxLive USB Creator (LiLi).

Comment: also, Unetbootin may be a solution.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

It is possible that windows 8 will not allow you to install Ubuntu by LiveCD/USB or Wubi. This is because Windows 8 introduced several new features, of which 2 are:

**UEFI** which substitutes what we have known as the BIOS (Is an alternative to)

**Secure Boot which prevents anything but the installed operating system**, in this case Windows 8 from booting.

[See this article for installing Ubuntu on Windows 8.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system)

Generally Speaking, there are two major ways of installing Ubuntu, without a CD.

One:

You can **create an ubuntu liveusb** and install ubuntu on a dedicated partition (or inside a windows partition, this works as well). If you want to do this, [see this article](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) on how to create an Ubuntu live usb.

Two:

You can **install Ubuntu via Wubi**. [Wubi](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-with-windows) is an windows installer for Ubuntu. Wubi creates a big file, let's say on your Windows where it install Ubuntu. The downside of using Wubi is that you cannot recreate a dedicated Ubuntu partition by using the wubi method.

Answer (score 1):

I have another solution that may be safer than what you are trying to do. I have Windows 2000 installed on Kubuntu 12.04 via the Virtual Box software. One can download the VirtualBox software from Oracle for Windows. The Virtual Box sets up the installation for you.

I think this is a safer idea if you want to try Linux on your ASUS Windows 8 Laptop. Some on these threads are talking about horror stories trying to do a dual boot with Windows 8 etc. This method is very safe!

Answer (score 0):

It can be done, yes. Use 12.10 64-bit or 12.04.2 LTS 64-bit. Make a USB-Stick, boot it and choose "try Ubuntu". Then install.